# How do I make this exact soap call?

Tags: php, xml, soap, talend

To start off with, I am a beginner at soap.

I am trying to make a soap call to a service and was given a working sample that comes from talend.  What I need is to make a similar call in PHP.

The output from talend is as follows, (extracted from the HTTP request)

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <root>
      <request>
        <username>a@a.com</username>
        <password>md5sumlookalike</password>
        <webservice>GetCust</webservice>
        <refid>12343321</refid>
        <message>reserv#123</message>
      </request>
    </root>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

So I wrote a little bit of PHP as it works as a scripting language as well for where it will be called from.  Trying to understand how to make a soap call I came up with this bit.

```
<?php
// Yes I know about the diffrent port issue here.  So I wgeted and stored it for use next to script
#   $soapClient = new SoapClient("http://123.123.123.123:8088/services", array("trace" => true)); 
    $soapClient = new SoapClient("wsdl", array("trace" => true)); 

    $error = 0; 
    try {   
        $info = $soapClient->__soapCall("invoke",
            array
            (
            new SoapParam("a@a.com", "username"),
            new SoapParam("md5sumish", "password"),
            new SoapParam("GetCust", "webservice"),
            new SoapParam("1234321", "refid"),
            new SoapParam("reserv#123", "message")

            )
        ); 
    } catch (SoapFault $fault) { 
        $error = 1; 
        echo 'ERROR: '.$fault->faultcode.'-'.$fault->faultstring; 
    } 

    if ($error == 0) { 
        print_r($output_headers);
        echo 'maybe it worked\n';
        unset($soapClient); 
    }   

?>
```

I end up seeing the following in the HTTP request via wireshark.  The server just does not know what to do with this and does not respond.  I am unsure what/where I need to go from here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://talend.org/esb/service/job">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:invokeInput>a@a.com</ns1:invokeInput>
    <password>md5sumish</password>
    <webservice>GetCust</webservice>
    <refid>1234321</refid>
    <message>reserv#123</message>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

So I have to ask is how to get rid of the ns1:invokeInput and make it username.  Along with bring the rest of the format into line so the request looks like the output from talend?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working little script I did in php to call a talend tutorial service exported as soap:

```
//....
if (sizeof($_POST) > 0) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $client = new SoapClient("http://192.168.32.205:8080/DirectoryService/services/DirectoryService?wsdl", array( 'trace' => 1));

    $result = $client->runJob(array(
        '--context_param',
        'Name=' . $_POST['name'],
        '--context_param',
        'City=' . $_POST['city']
    ));
}
//...
```

Talend seems to be very "basic" regarding how parameters are given. 
With this code it was working fine.